# Dependency Management using BOWER

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bower, dependency-management

I have a angular application which requires like 20 different libraries:

```
<script src="/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.1.1/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>
<script src="http://desandro.github.io/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/plugins/fushion/fusioncharts.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/plugins/pace-master/pace.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/plugins/jquery-blockui/jquery.blockui.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/plugins/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/plugins/switchery/switchery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/plugins/uniform/jquery.uniform.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/plugins/offcanvasmenueffects/js/classie.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/plugins/offcanvasmenueffects/js/main.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/plugins/waves/waves.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/plugins/3d-bold-navigation/js/main.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/plugins/ion.rangeslider/js/ion.rangeSlider.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/plugins/metrojs/MetroJs.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/modern.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/plugins/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://passy.github.io/angular-masonry/angular-masonry.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/rz-slider.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/plugins/fushion/angular-fusioncharts.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/angular-translate.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/angular-translate-loader-static-files.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/tmhDynamicLocale.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/calendar/calendar.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.js" data-semver="v2.2.4"></script>
<script src="//mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.tpl.js" data-semver="v2.2.4"></script>
<script src="//mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/docs/angular-strap.docs.tpl.js" data-semver="v2.2.4"></script>
<script src="/assets/plugins/lightbox/js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/ocLazyLoad.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-translate-storage-cookie/2.6.1/angular-translate-storage-cookie.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-translate-storage-local/2.6.1/angular-translate-storage-local.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/ng-infinite-scroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<!-- Maps -->
<script src="/assets/js/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/angular-google-maps.js"></script>
<script src="/application-modules/app.js"></script>
```

Now I want to manage it in a better way. I was looking at bower and gulp as the candidates.

So I have a couple of questions:

1. How do I manage dependencies? In the list above many libraries requires angular version 2.1 but then a library masonry requires angular version 3.1. How do I fix such things?
2. how do i load my custom js files
3. Many plugins requires CSS as well. Bower has that covered?
4. What could be my best approach to implement bower setup on the above list. What I essentially want to do is : First implement bower keeping angular version as 1.2 so I would need all the dependencies to be resolved properly. And then, I would want to upgrade angular version and I would expect all the dependencies upgradation to be taken care of.

Please put some light on the above concerns.